# Play custom sound when typing in custom keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audio, keyboard

I am building a custom Keyboard extension for my application. When the user clicks one key, a custom Tone called "Tock.mp3" should play. It's not the same as the system tone.

I have 4 Objective-C classes and one .xib file. They're called KeyboardViewController.h/.m, Keyboard.h/.m/.xib

I'll attach the code of the classes at the end.
So, I tried the following:

```
 NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                               pathForResource:@"Tock"
                                               ofType:@"mp3"]];
    AVAudioPlayer *click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
    [click setVolume:0.15f];
    [click play];
```

My question: What code do I need and where do I have to implement it?

Here's the code for KeyboardViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface KeyboardViewController : UIInputViewController
@end
```

KeyboardViewController.m:

```
#import "KeyboardViewController.h"
#import "Keyboard.h"

@interface KeyboardViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic)Keyboard *keyboard;

@end

@implementation KeyboardViewController

- (void)updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];

    // Add custom view sizing constraints here
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Perform custom UI setup here
    self.keyboard = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Keyboard" owner:nil options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
    [self addGesturesToKeyboard];
    self.inputView = self.keyboard;
    ;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
}

- (void)textWillChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput {
    // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
}

- (void)textDidChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput {
    // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.

    UIColor *textColor = nil;
    if (self.textDocumentProxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearanceDark) {
        textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else {
        textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
#pragma mark Keyboards
-(void)addGesturesToKeyboard
{
    [self.keyboard.backKey addTarget:self action:@selector(pressDeleteKey) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.keyboard.leerzeichenKey addTarget:self action:@selector(pressLeerzeichenKey) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.keyboard.enterKey addTarget:self action:@selector(pressEnterKey) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.keyboard.numbersKey addTarget:self action:@selector(pressNumbersKey) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //Change to next Keyboard
    [self.keyboard.globeKey addTarget:self action:@selector(advanceToNextInputMode) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    for (UIButton * key in self.keyboard.KeysArray) {
        [key addTarget:self action:@selector(pressKey:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }

  }
-(void)pressDeleteKey
{
    [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];
}
-(void)pressLeerzeichenKey
{
    [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:@" "];
}
-(void)pressEnterKey
{
    [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:@"\n"];
}
-(void)pressKey: (UIButton*) key
{
    [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:[[key currentTitle]lowercaseString]];
}
-(void)pressNumbersKey
{
}

@end
```

Keyboard.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface Keyboard : UIView 


@property (strong,nonatomic)IBOutletCollection(UIButton)NSArray *KeysArray;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *upKey;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *numbersKey;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *globeKey;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *leerzeichenKey;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *enterKey;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *backKey;

@end
```

And finally, my Keyboard.m (not pretty much! :D):

```
#import "Keyboard.h"

@implementation Keyboard
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **KeyboardViewController.m** I would create a method like this:

```
-(void)playSound
{
    NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Tock"ofType:@"mp3"]];
    AVAudioPlayer *click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
    [click setVolume:0.15f];
    [click play];
}
```

And then I would call this method in each of this event handlers:

```
-(void)pressDeleteKey
{
    **[self playSound];**
    [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];
}
-(void)pressLeerzeichenKey
{
    **[self playSound];**
    [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:@" "];
}
-(void)pressEnterKey
{
    **[self playSound];**
    [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:@"\n"];
}
-(void)pressKey: (UIButton*) key
{
    **[self playSound];**
    [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:[[key currentTitle]lowercaseString]];
}
-(void)pressNumbersKey
{
    **[self playSound];**
}
```

Instead of using a AVAudioPlayer to play back the sound I would convert the soundfile into a **.caf** file. To playback **.caf** files see [Easiest way to play a CAF sound on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817175/easiest-way-to-play-a-caf-sound-on-the-iphone)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, Thank You really much! I'll try that tommorow. If I have question, I'll ask you!

Comment: @user3786233 Does this option work for you? In my case I'm not able to hear the sound.